# When does Emacs Lisp's lexical-let leak memory?

Tags: emacs, memory-leaks, elisp

I read about lexical-let's memory leak, for example here:
[Are there any problems with lexical-let or other cl-macros??? - Users list for the GNU Emacs text editor - ArchiveOrange](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/LEGAoPlXgvXa9iJfMyLe)

It says:

> "Note that variables bound with lexical-let are never released, even
>   if they are never used. Try
>
> ```
> (loop for i from 1 to 100000 collect (lexical-let ((x i)) '()))
> ```
>
> and watch it eat memory."

But I think this code eats memory just because the list made by loop grows.
So, I wrote a few elisp codes to check when it occurs but I could not find a example of the leak.

This is how memory grows with time when I execute the code below.

[image: lambda-in-let.el]

```
(require 'cl)

(defvar num-loop-1 30)
(defvar num-loop-2 100000)

(loop for i from 1 to num-loop-1 do
      (loop for j from 1 to num-loop-2 collect
            (lexical-let ((x `(,i ,j))) (lambda () x))))
```

It looks like there is no leak.

See more examples here:
https://gist.github.com/1703325

ADDED: This is how the first example eats memory. As I said, I think it is an artifact.

[image: lambda-in-let.el]

Comment: FWIW here is the original archive page for the thread on `help-gnu-emacs`, without ads: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2010-12/msg00141.html

Comment: [emacs devel](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel) is a better place for this kind of question than SO

Comment: Also, #emacs channel on Freenode could be a good place to ask a question of this kind.

Comment: @JonO Thanks. I wil try use the official version from now on.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. As you suggested, I find that somebody just answered the question in emacs-devel: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2012-01/msg00939.html.

Comment: @vpit3833 Thanks. I don't use IRC but will try next time I have this kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this in [emacs-devel](http://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-devel):

> > [When does Emacs Lisp's lexical-let leak memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062580/when-does-emacs-lisps-lexical-let-leak-memory)
> >     So... Is it true, that "variables bound with lexical-let are never
> >     released, even if they are never used"?
>
> Not that I know.  Of course, this code is not bug-free, but I don't know
>   of any concrete case that bumps into such a bug.
>
> -- [Re: lexical-let cause memory leaks?](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2012-01/msg00939.html)